# How to parse a csv file in a mysql query

Tags: mysql, csv, mariadb

I am saving output of a mysql query to a .csv file. The output looks like below in a csv

```
RAD15;"5288469";"212273";"N;"https://www.google.com/sf/go/67933"
```

And this is snippet of my query for output

```
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/links.csv' FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

I need the below output instead of the one i gave above

```
RAD15,https://www.google.com/sf/go/67933
```

RAD15 in one column and the link in the second column

Comment: this is the complete query :





select CONCAT(si.ID_PREFIX, si.ID_COUNT) as ID, tmp.* from ( select ACTIVITY_ID, ISSUE_ID, OLD_VALUE, NEW_VALUE from SCARAB_ACTIVITY where ISSUE_ID in (select ISSUE_ID from SCARAB_ISSUE where MODULE_ID = 1112)  and (NEW_VALUE like 'http%') order by ACTIVITY_ID desc) tmp, SCARAB_ISSUE si where tmp.ISSUE_ID = si.ISSUE_ID INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/testing3.csv' FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY ',' TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';

Comment: Place this query into your question and edit it so that it is readable.

Comment: replace tmp.* with the exat column names. leave out ENCLOSED BY

Comment: @e4c5 yeah perfect but i need the NEW_VALUE only to find the links, but i dont want the NEWVALUE ID to be displayed
IS it possible that i remove that from the output but still use it for search

Comment: quite ppossible

Comment: @e4c5 can you give me an example relevant to my query

Comment: no because your question is most unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT col1, url
...
INTO OUTFILE
...
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '' TERMINATED BY ','
...
```